# How to stop Pandas from saving a csv by breaking lines?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tkinter, text

The csv output of a tkinter Text widget with line breaks is being saved like this:

```
"id","comment","name"
1,"ABC",Beth
2,"xyz",Peter
3,"abc
xyz",Mike
```

[image]

I tried to save using lineterminator=  both '\r\n' and only '\n' but without success. Some lines I used:

```
comment = Text(Forms, width=50, height=5 , wrap="word", font=('arial', 10))

df.at[id_q,'comment']=comment.get(1.0, "end-1c")

df.to_csv('./test.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, sep = ',' , lineterminator='\r\n')
```

---

I wanted the .cvs to look like this using the \n  instead of breaking:

```
"id","comment","name"
1,"ABC",Beth
2,"xyz",Peter
3,"abc\nxyz",Mike
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Entry` instead of `Text` if you don't want to have line break inside an input?

Comment: Because it is a large amount of text. I want \n to appear in the csv itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.decode()` and `str.encode()` to convert the newline to escape string as below:

```py
df.at[id_q,'comment'] = comment.get('1.0', 'end-1c').encode('unicode_escape').decode()
```

Note that it is for Python 3.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Probably worth adding that when reading the csv file again later, they can get back to the strings with line breaks using `df['comment'] = df['comment'].apply(lambda x: x.encode().decode('unicode-escape'))`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is that there are line breaks in the cell content, so these will be present in the csv output regardless of the line terminator.

Something like the following should work:

```
df.at[id_q,'comment']=comment.get(1.0, "end-1c").replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
```

Comment: Hi, ljdyer. Thanks for listening. This replaces worked, avoiding the break in the csv, but now I don't know when there is a line break.

Comment: @acw1668's answer has you covered!